# How to access "key" and "value" from an array passed to a for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

How can I change the `foreach` loop below so that I can assign the `$myradiooption` array's `key` as the `value` for each input instead of the array's `option` value as I'm now doing (I still want to echo the array's `option` value as the label)?

```php
<?php
$myradiooptions = array(
    "grid1" => "Grid View (default)",
    "list1" => "List View (1 column)",
    "list2" => "List View (2 column)" 
  );

array(
  "name" => "Category Layout",
  "desc" => "description goes here",
  "id" => "my_category_layout",
  "type" => "radio",
  "options" => $myradiooptions )
);
//switch, case "radio":
?>
<li class="section">
  <label
    class="left"
    for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
      <?php echo $value['name']; ?>
  </label>
  <?php
    $count=1;
    foreach ($value['options'] as $option) {
  ?>
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"
    id="<?php echo $count; ?>"
    value="<?php echo $option; ?>"
    <?php checked($option, get_settings($value['id'])); ?>
  />
  <label style="color:#666; margin:0 20px 0 5px;" for="<?php echo $count; ?>">
    <?php echo $option; ?>
  </label>
  <?php $count++;} ?>
  <label class="description" style="margin-top:-5px;">
    <?php echo $value['desc']; ?>
  </label>
</li>
<?php break;
```

Comment: I would suggest that you improve your formatting.  That code is a big jumble.  Use consistent indenting and use linebreaks to try to keep your code concise and clear...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
foreach ($value['options'] as $key=>$option)
```

Now you can access the key as `$key`, and the option as `$option`

Answer (score 9):

If you want to access the key of an array in a foreach loop, you use the following syntax:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { ... }
```

References: [`foreach` in the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to extract key/value pairs from an associative array,  simply use...

```
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $value) {
   ...
}
```

...as per the [PHP foreach manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 1):

the whole thing can be changed to something like this for better readability...

```
<?php

$myradiooptions = array(
                    "grid1" => "Grid View (default)", 
                    "list1" => "List View (1 column)", 
                    "list2" => "List View (2 column)" 
                  );

$value = array(  
            "name" => "Category Layout",
            "desc" => "description goes here",
            "id" => "my_category_layout",
            "type" => "radio",
            "options" => $myradiooptions 
         );

foreach($value as $key => $val)
{
    $formHTML = "<label class='left' for='{$value['id']}'>".$value['name']."</label>";
    if(is_array($val))
    {
        $count = 1;
        foreach($val as $k => $v)
        {
            $formHTML .= "<input type='radio' name='{$v['id']}' id='$count' value='$v' /><label style='color:#666; margin:0 20px 0 5px;' for='$count'>$v</label>";
            $count ++;
        }
    }
    $formHTML .= "<label class='description' style='margin-top:-5px;'>".$value['desc']."</label>";
}

//switch, case "radio":
?>
<li class="section">
    <?php print $formHTML; ?>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should explain it pretty well:

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/295/php-syntax-iterate-over-an-associative-array/